# WordPress Child-Themes & Footers

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a child-theme of Oxygen, a free WordPress theme and I'm having trouble with the footer.

Everywhere I've read is either outdated or for another theme and useless to me. I have copied `footer.php` to my theme but they insert the footer a little different to the examples I've seen making it harder for me to edit. I want to keep it mostly the same so I'd prefer to use their method but I don't understand what is happening.

Here's some of the footer.php file:

```
    <div id="footer">

        <?php do_atomic( 'open_footer' ); // oxygen_open_footer ?>

        <div id="footer-content" class="footer-content">

            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'footer_content', hybrid_get_setting( 'footer_insert' ) ); ?>

        </div>

        <?php get_template_part( 'menu', 'subsidiary' ); // Loads the menu-subsidiary.php template.  ?>

        <?php do_atomic( 'footer' ); // oxygen_footer ?>

        <?php do_atomic( 'close_footer' ); // oxygen_close_footer ?>

    </div><!-- #footer -->
```

As far as I can tell, it calls the following function in functions.php:

```
function oxygen_default_footer_settings( $settings ) {

    $settings['footer_insert'] = '<p class="copyright">' . __( 'Copyright &#169; [the-year] [site-link]', 'oxygen' ) . '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p class="credit">' . __( 'Powered by [wp-link] and [theme-link]', 'oxygen' ) . '</p>';

    return $settings;
}
```

I tried copying that function to my `functions.php` file applying the edits but had no luck.

Using the same methods, how would I go about changing the footer?

Comment: `get_template_part( 'menu', 'subsidiary' )` is loading the file `menu-subsidiary.php` into the page. Basically just including all of the code in that php file. If you open that file (it should be in your theme's root) and read it's code there should be more to your footer. You'll also be able to find out more if you can find the function do_atomic() in your theme's source. It's likely in functions.php. I'm not familiar with that function or theme, so I can't tell you much more.

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself. In any case, just copying a function is not enough unless it has been made pluggable on purpose. `do_action` calls for any actions registered to it, which you can do with the add_action function. I'm guessing do_atomic works as a wrapper for do_action, you'd have to inspect that code in more detail to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing what I wanted. Probably the most direct as well.

I simply replaced:

```php
<?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'footer_content', hybrid_get_setting( 'footer_insert' ) ); ?>
```

with:

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode( '<p class="copyright">' . __( 'Copyright &#169; [the-year] [site-link]', 'oxygen' ) . '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p class="credit">' . __( 'Powered by [wp-link] and [author]', 'oxygen' ) . '</p>' ); ?>
```